# Different results with Memtest86

Tags: bsod, diagnostic, memtest

I've recently run a Memtest on my computer which have 2 x 4gb DDR3 RAM sticks due to a lot of MEMORY_MANAGEMENT bsods. The result showed 4 errors in a run of 10,5 hours (8 passes) so clearly something is wrong. I then ran a Memtest with only one of the sticks plugged in to figure which one is causing the errors. But now I can't seem to reproduce any errors with only one RAM stick. Is that even possible? What do you suggest that I do to pinpoint what exactly the error is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used both slots for single memory module tests?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but I physically removed the stick from the motherboard and ran Memtest on each of the 4gb.

Comment: "I can't seem to reproduce any errors with only one RAM stick. Is that even possible?" Yes, timing issues between the RAM sticks can cause errors only when more than one stick is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 errors in the course of 10 hours isn't *necessarily* indicative of bad ram. For example, it could be a bad power supply that can't handle dramatic changes in input voltage.

Realistically, when you have bad ram it is a repeatable problem. it won't work one time and not another. I'd start looking for other culprits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you suggest that I look for then?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your setup, but I used to see cheap power supplies cause a multitude of problems when I worked in the shop. If you have any spares I'd try switching that out and running it for 10 hours and see if that solves any problems. Someone above me pointed out that it might be the slot itself, that's totally possible too.